# How to check whether Connection Refresh was successful

Tags: vba, excel, powerquery

In Excel 2016 VBA, I'm refreshing several queries like this:

```
MyWorkbook.Connections(MyConnectionName).Refresh
```

After the code is done, and no errors are encountered, I see that the hourglass icons for most of the queries are still spinning for several seconds.

Is it possible to check for success AFTER all the refreshes are completed? I'm concerned that my code isn't going to know if an error happens after the code finishes but before the queries are done refreshing.

BTW I don't want to do a RefreshAll, because some of the queries are dependent on others (uses them as a source). I refresh them in a certain sequence so that dependent queries are refreshed after the queries they are dependent on.

UPDATE:

I see that the Connection objects have a read-only RefreshDate property, which at first glance looked like it could be used to do this check:

```
MyWorkbook.Connections(MyConnectionName).OLEDBConnection.RefreshDate
```

HOWEVER, it doesn't seem to be getting set. I get an error trying to check it. If I set a Variant variable to that RefreshDate property, the variable shows as "Empty". The source is a SQL server database.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `QueryTable` object exposes two events: `BeforeRefresh` and `AfterRefresh`.

You need to change your paradigm from procedural/imperative to event-driven.

Say you have this code in `ThisWorkbook` (won't work in a standard procedural code module, because `WithEvents` can only be in a class):

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents table As Excel.QueryTable
Private currentIndex As Long
Private tables As Variant

Private Sub table_AfterRefresh(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    Debug.Print table.WorkbookConnection.Name & " refreshed. (success: " & Success & ")"
    currentIndex = currentIndex + 1
    If Success And currentIndex <= UBound(tables) Then
        Set table = tables(currentIndex)
        table.Refresh
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Test()
    tables = Array(Sheet1.ListObjects(1).QueryTable, Sheet2.ListObjects(1).QueryTable)
    currentIndex = 0
    Set table = tables(currentIndex)
    table.Refresh
End Sub
```

The `tables` variable contains an array of `QueryTable` objects, ordered in the order you wish to refresh them; the `currentIndex` variable points to the index in that array, for the `QueryTable` you want to act upon.

So when `Test` runs, we initialize the `tables` array with the `QueryTable` objects we want to refresh, *in the order we want to refresh them*.

The implicit, event-driven loop begins when `table.Refresh` is called and the `QueryTable` fires its `AfterRefresh` event: then we report success, and update the event-provider `table` object reference with the next `QueryTable` in the array (only if the refresh was successful), and call its `Refresh` method, which will fire `AfterRefresh` again, until the entire array has been traversed or one of them failed to update.

Comment: Thanks, that works great. I had one query that was connection only, so I had to load it to a table so that it would have a ListObject and therefore a Querytable. That added a little bit of file size but it was a small price to pay for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

Just found this solution at [Execute code after a data connection is refreshed](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/564959-execute-code-after-data-connection-refresh-finished.html)

The bottom line is: Excel refreshes data connection in the background and thus the rest of the code is executed without interruption.

Solution: set `BackgroundQuery` property to `False`

Example:

```
For Each cnct In ThisWorkbook.Connections
   cnct.ODBCConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
Next cnct
```

Possible problem: don't know which connection it is...

Remedy: case... when...

```
Dim cnct as WorkbookConnection ' if option explicit
' ODBC and OLE DB
For Each cnct In ThisWorkbook.Connections
   Select case cnct.type
      case xlconnectiontypeodbc
   cnct.ODBCConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
      case xlconnectiontypeoledb
    cnct.OledbConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
   end select
Next cnct
```

As you can see, code above only deals with **ODBC** and **OLE DB**. Depending on what types of data connection you are using, you can expand the select case clause. Unless changed, once run, connection's `BackgroundQuery` will remain off.

Comment: Thanks, but I haven't looked at this code for nearly two years. It was for a contract that ended long ago. The only connection I have with this project now is using that manager as a reference for new contracts.  :-)

Comment: Oh sorry to hear about it... I just start to deal with this recently so that's why I found your post very helpful and want to offer an alternative. Best of luck with your future endeavors!

Answer (score 0):

Although not a precise solution, I identified a quirky work-around to display the error messages that Power Query would generally display, even when triggering a refresh from VBA. The caveat is that it will refresh all queries, but I propose a method to deal with that later on.

We all know that when you call the `Workbook.RefreshAll` method from VBA, for some reason, when using it with `Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone`, all the Power Query Error messages get suppressed.

However, when you click on the 'Refresh All' button from the 'Data' tab of the Excel Ribbon, the error messages are displayed. Fortunately, you can trigger a ribbon command call from VBA using the `CommandBars.ExecuteMso` method. So I tried to call the button, and it worked - the error messages were displayed.

You need the `idMso` property of the 'Refresh All' button to trigger the command. It is `"RefreshAll"` - no surprises there.

Here is a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbars.executemso) to an post that helps you get the `idMso` property for popular commands.

Calling something like this did the trick for me:

```
Application.CommandBars("Queries and Connections").Visible = True
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "RefreshAll"
Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone
```

Note that I am opening the 'Queries and Connections' pane just so the user is aware of the status as it is happening. This is optional. And I do not set `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` since that freezes the pane also.

I have noticed that in some Excel Versions, you might have to set all the query connections' `BackgroundQuery` property to `True` for the `Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone` method to work properly.

Now the error messages that Power Query Natively displays, get displayed when errors occur.

I'd also like to address the one shortcoming of this approach with a final tip. If you do not want to refresh all the queries, you can write some code to alter the `WorkbookConnection.RefreshWithRefreshAll` property of the connections you do not want to execute, to stop it from executing when the 'Refresh All' button is clicked. Here is a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbookconnection.refreshwithrefreshall) to the documentation of that property.

The advantage of this approach is that, when refreshing all queries, Power Query deals with the Query Dependencies while using a shared cache - so it is better/faster than triggering individual query refreshes with code.